# Easyadmin symfony 3 third level submenu

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I was figuring out how to put a third level menu in easyadmin (Symfony 3), i tried:

```
- label: 'Menu 1'
  children:
     - label: 'Menu 2'
       children: 
         - { entity: 'MyEntity' , ... }
```

But it is not showing the third level menu items:

### [image]

I looked up into the source code of easyadmin (https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/blob/master/src/Configuration/MenuConfigPass.php) and it seems that it only process 2nd level menu items. Has anybody achieve the third level submenu ?

Appreciate any help !

--

Thanks.